# Can I fit a bigger tire on my bike

Tags: wheels, rims, upgrades

[image]

This is an old 70’s huffy.. with 20" wheel rims and 1.75 tires.

I have some 24 inch rims to install, but the pegs are bigger in diameter, so they don’t fit in the fork's dropouts.

Are the old type rims available with the small pegs and would they fit on the bike it I find them?  There seems to be space enough to not rub?

Comment: Did you measure that if you got a 24" rim in that you'd have adequate clearance for a tire in the frame+fork?

Comment: Yes it looks like i’ll Have about a 1/2 in or slightly less..what have are 24 tires and rims but the pegs on them are thicker than the fork slots

Comment: by "pegs" I think you mean "axle diameter".  They are not pegs for standing on.   Can you measure the outside diameter of the axle using a caliper, and the inside gap in the fork dropouts?  If the difference is really small filing should be okay, but I wouldn't remove more than 0.2mm.   A thin axle implies the bike is for children-sized riders and may not carry a modern-day child or adult.

Comment: Save yourself some time and just hold one of your 24" wheels up inside the fork.  Resting the dropouts on the larger axle should give you an idea of whether it will fit inside the forks and have room to spin freely.   If that doesn't work, there's little point struggling to fit 24" into this frame.

Comment: Thx you for ur reply’s!! I’ll get back if I need more help!!:)